# Making an enterprise application more robust - ASP.NET/C#

Tags: asp.net, architecture

I am working with a team of 10 developers in enhancing an enterprise app built on .NET/C# and SQL Server 2005. The application is mature and large but there are lots of opportunities for improvement in terms of reusability, scalability and performance.

I would like to help in making the application more robust and would like to know where I could pick up suggestions/tips related to ASP.NET and SQL Server. As an example, I helped in adding Memcache to the application that made the application perform faster. I am not looking only for major enhancements - the smaller ones help too. One of the smaller changes we made was in creating a library that encrypts hidden data making the app more secure (Earlier, the hidden input form fields were not encrypted)

I haven't worked with larger apps before and my experience lacks in this area. Any online resources, websites, books, whitepapers, articles that would help me in my quest?

Answer (score 1):

- Compress and optimize the ViewState.
- Minify javascript
- Sensitive data should never be on hidden fields (encrypted or not)

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site), most of it applies to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Framework Design Guidelines - Cwalina & Adams

[image]

Read it.
Interpret it appropriately.
Use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much your team focuses on usability, but I've been doing a lot of reading about it lately. Specifically, this book:

[GUI Bloopers 2.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123706432)

If you make sure you're not committing any of the bloopers in there you'll be doing your users a huge favor. The most interesting section for me involved the perception of speed. Even if you optimize a certain algorithm to be faster, the users might still have the *perception* that it's slow.  That's what really impacts how people feel about your app.